# Run same program on multiple files in a directory

Tags: c++, recursion, text, file-handling

I have a directory which contains thousands of .txt files and sub folders with even more files. I need to run a C++ parsing program that goes into the main folder and run on every text file that is in the folder and its subfolders

So how should i proceed?

EDIT: So the question that has been linked gets the directory traversal part right but the main issue is that how can i "pass each text file" to my program in the directory

Comment: `find -name "*.txt" -exec myprogram {} \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>I am assuming you are on Linux or some other POSIX system</sup>

You could use the [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command (as commented by [Niels Keurentjes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729885/niels-keurentjes)) to start a different process for every file. Since a new process would be started for each file, there is no significant limitation (but of course, starting a million processes take some time, even for very short lived processes; you might spend several milliseconds of starting time - or a few dozen of them - per process, plus the proper process time).

If each file processing is quick, you might want to avoid the overhead of starting a process for each of them. Then you'll do the recursive file tree scanning with the [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) library function (and give it your handling function, which might be very quick and take a few microseconds if you are careful enough, and if the processing is simple & fast). AFAIK, it is able to handle very fat file trees.

Alternatively, use `find` to output a file list, and have your program parse that file list and process each file path in turn. Or embed some interpreter (like [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [lua](http://lua.org/) ....) in your program, write a script to scan the directory, and have it call a function in your program for every file.

BTW, handling a fat file tree of several millions of files should not be a problem (and should be done in a reasonable time, a few minutes or hours; the bottleneck might be the disk I/O)

PS. See also the *Answers* table of [this page](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) for *Approximate timing for various operations on some PC*

Comment: Will the "find" method work for 550k text files?

Comment: Of course yes, even a billion text files, if you have enough time

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. For everyone that needs to run a program on multiple files use the "line method" as seen in the comments with a slight modification i.e.
find -name "*.txt" -exec ./myParser {} \;
notice the part before myParser
And you'll need to use the command line arguments for passing the file you give to your parser/program

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the boost-type solutions in that linked question, there's sample old-fashioned code for recursing through a directory structure [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip2.htm).